# If $W$,$V$ are independent, geometric random variables, what is the distribution of $Z \sim W + V$?

Tags: probability-distributions, convolution

**Question:** If $W$,$V$ are independent geometric random variables, what is the distribution of  $Z \sim W + V$?

Please note, $W \sim Geometric(3/5)$ and $V \sim Geometric(7/12)$.

Also,
$P(W=w) = (1-\frac{3}{5})^{w}\frac{3}{5}$ for $w = 0,1,2, \dots$

$P(V=v) = (1-\frac{7}{12})^{v}\frac{7}{12}$ for $v = 0,1,2, \dots$

**What I have so far:** I have looked around already on  mathexchange and usually the geometric pdf is different to the one I am defining (with $1-p$ to the power of $w-1$ instead of just $w$). I know to use convolution however I am unsure of how to simplify the sum, I am also unsure of if my limits are wrong.

My working:

$P(W+V=z)= \sum_{w=0}^z P(W=w)P(V=z-w) $

$= \frac{3}{5} \frac{7}{12}  \sum_{w=0}^z (\frac{2}{5})^{w}(\frac{5}{12})^{z-w}$

$= \frac{3}{5} \frac{7}{12}  \sum_{w=0}^z (\frac{24}{25})^{w}(\frac{5}{12})^{z}$

$= \frac{3}{5} \frac{7}{12} (\frac{5}{12})^{z} \sum_{w=0}^z (\frac{24}{25})^{w}$

My biggest question is if my limits on the sum are correct and where do I go from here?

Comment: Is it known that these variables are independent?

Comment: @jMdA yes they are

Comment: Individual distributions do not determine the distribution  of the sum. It is a serious mistake not to mention independence.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I had a lot of information to get across. Its been mentioned in the comments and I will edit the post. Calm down.

Comment: I write this comment often because the most common mistake made by students of Statistics and Probability is assuming indepednece when that is not given. I just want to help you avoid this mistake so tha you don't  loose points in exams. I am as cool as one can be.

Comment: It is mentioned. It is my mistake for not writing it in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

The sum of a geometric series is $$\sum_{i=0}^{n} a^i = \frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$$.

You can use this on the step where you're stuck.